# parent div inheriting child divs margin

Tags: html, css

It doesnt happen all the time but, every once in a while, The parent div inherits the child divs properties and throws my layouts positioning out of whack.

for example, this is the html(pseudo):

```
<div 1>
   <div 2>
      content here
   </div>

</div><!-- div one end -->
```

the Css (pseudo):

```
#1{ margin top:0; }
#2 {margin top:10 }
```

its supposed to look like this:
div 1 the parent and div 2 the child

div 1parent

```
-----------------------------------------
this is address bar (top of win)
-----------------------------------------
----------------
|  ----------  |
| | div2Child  |
| ------------ |
|--------------|
```

assume that there isnt a gap from div 1 to addy window.

now, for some odd reason, using the same code above, when i preview, i get this:

```
-----------------------------------------
this is address bar (top of win)
-----------------------------------------

gap here.

----------------
|  ----------  |
| |   div2     |
| ------------ |
|--------------|
```

no matter what i do i still get that gap. When i take it to firebug and test on the Divs,
div2 clearly shows that the margin is affecting the parents positioning.

..i was going to put up an example but...well heres the actual code so you can see...(simple as can be)

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">content here on 2</div>
</div>

the CSS: 

    #one{
        width:1000px;
        height:300px;
        background:#09F;
        margin-top:0px !important;
padding:0px;


    }

    #two{
        width:500px;
        height:100px;
        background:red;
        margin-top:20px;
padding:0px;
    }
```

and i still get the gap i showed above in my diagram. What drives me crazy is, like most of us, weve done this layout millions of times....i can pull up DOZENS of works that use this same method and no problems...i have my Cssreset that i always use. have the !important, no random `<br/> or <p>` , 0 padding... matter of fact to make SURE, i created a dummy page with nothing but the 2 divs and their css and still........

Any thoughts as to why this happens? cause right now im looking at my last site create and this dummy html i just made to test and on every browser, i get that stupid gap.

Comment: sometimes margins are ignored when they are going to affect on each other, meaning if there is top margin of 20 and bottom margin of 20 on the top div, the margin between will be 20, maybe this is a similar case.. Paste some HTML and CSS I'll try to look into this in and post a solution on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well thats all the html there is lol. literally, if you look at the bott of my post, that html there is the html i added on a blank page to test this mess...and i get the gap...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're observing is margin-collapse. It can happen in scenarios that aren't always straightforward to understand, so I suggest referring to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
#one{
        width:1000px;
        height:300px;
        background:#09F;
        margin-top:0px !important;
        padding-top:20px;
    }
    #two{
        width:500px;
        height:100px;
        background:red;
        margin-top:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }​
```

?
just wondering

Comment: well because, i mean i CAN, but thats not what i want you know...i cant stand looking for workarounds in stupid little problems like this....but you are 100% correct lol.

Comment: kinakuta posted exactly what you are looking for. Check out the "Parent and first/last child" section